# Use Data Extension data in Journey Builder in real time

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I would like to have a real time Journey Builder with data incoming from a Data extension.

I have a Data extension which is filled with data, similar than a Smart Capture Data extension, but a normal one.
I need that every time a record is added to that Data extension (via Web Collect), that records enters in real time in the Journey builder.

It used to work setting a scheduled hourly Automation with blocks of fire event+wait in between every 5 minutes, but it's not working anymore.

Comment: Have you tried Journey Builder API on form submit or does this need to be done internally on SFMC side?

Comment: I'd prefer to be on SFMC side. 
I've already tried vía API and it does work, but I have to give it to my customer several times, so if I can avoid that step, better for us.
API needs to be changed every time I change my Data Extension, so it's not fittable for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a journey with that a email studio audience.

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/journey_builder_audiences/create_an_email_studio_audience/

When you create this ensure you set the journey to evaluate new records only and not allow re entry. (so you're only processing new records)

You can have this run hourly.

If you want something closer to real time you can use a automation studio audience in your journey.

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/journey_builder_audiences/create_an_automation_studio_audience/

You'd be able to have it trigger within a minute or two of entry this way.

Comment: I am not beig able to do the second option -automation studio audience-, the automation runs every hour and it does not trigger the sendable data extension into the Journey Builder.

Could you explain me how did you do that?

Comment: Sure! So in the documentation it states "An automation that includes an activity that creates or refreshes a sendable data extension must exist to create a Journey Builder audience. Automation Studio activities that manage sendable data extensions are SQL Query, Filter, or Import activities." 

so what this means is the DE you want to trigger off needs to have a activity like a query on the DE you want to send to via the journey.

This can be as simple as you have a automation with a hourly run with a query that copies the data from your original DE into a new one.

Comment: or if you wanted you could have a hourly automation with a query on the DE that does nothing. For example updating a field with a where condition that would never be met.

Comment: Thanks, but it still works only once an hour. There is no trigger that makes it possible within a minute or two.
I've already settled an DE with a filter activity in the Automation Studio. But when I add contacts to my DE, it only works 1 time an hour, when it's scheduled by the automation.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: No problem. File drop import automations run as soon as a file is dropped into your FTP account so that would be the way around this. Unfortunately it might be a lot of work to get this happening given your current method of web collect as you'd need to create a file for the automation to import. (and get it to your FTP)

If you consider looking into it the kind of automation is detailed here: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/triggered_automations/